# Linq, combining multiple records into comma separated string, grouped by distinct value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do a groupby distinct, then build a csv string:

[image]

[FROM] is a one-to-many join:

```
        var allCustomerRoles = (from cr in Customers
                                join r in CustomerRoles
                                on cr.Role_ID equals r.Role_ID
                                select new { cr.Customer_No_, r.Role_ID });
```

So the question is, can you please show me how to write the LINQ query to arrive at the [TO] structure, where Customer_No_ is distinct and it's Role_ID values are concatenated into a CSV string.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what problem you are experiencing?

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more descriptive, edited original post.

Comment: This link can probalby help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: @Réda Mattar, that's it!  I knew the answer was out there somewhere...thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you @reda-mattar, your link led me to the solution, here's what I was looking for:

```
var allCustomerRoles = (from cr in Customers
                        join r in Roles
                        on cr.Role_ID equals r.Role_ID
                        group r.Role_ID by cr.Customer_No_ into g
                        select new { Customer_No_ = g.Key, Role_ID = string.Join(",", g.ToArray()) });
```

Comment: @Joe C that really helped